# Change atop log interval from 10 minutes to 1 minute

Tags: atop

I'm having post-mortem `atop` log on Ubuntu machine, which I'm able to view with

```
atop -r
```

The problem is that log files are shown in 10 minute intervals with `t` and `Shift+t`, while I would prefer 1 minute intervals. When current time is changed with `b`, it is quantized to nearest 10 minute point.

I have a line in `/etc/init.d/atop`, but I'm not sure if it affects anything here:

```
INTERVAL=60
```

How can I make `atop` logs to be browsed with 1 minute accuracy with `t` and `Shift+t`?

Is the information between these 10 minute intervals already lost?

What are the possible workarounds if this is not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following line to `/etc/atoprc`, if the file doesn't exist create it:

```
interval 60
```

atop no longer uses the `/etc/default/atop` file.

Unless you are using an older version of `atop`. Then you might want to change `INTERVAL=600` to `INTERVAL=60` in `/etc/default/atop`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, only editing /etc/default/atop could help.

Comment: Your welcome. I find atop to be a very useful utility.

Answer (score 8):

On recent versions the configuration file used by systemd is `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily` (see `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/atop.service`).

Here you can change the variable `INTERVAL` and restart the `atop` service.

Comment: That was the one comment helping me out on Ubuntu 18.04, thank you!
As one can see on `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily` it isn't really sourcing the /etc/atoprc. And even if the program itself respects it, specifying the INTERVAL via a command line parameter will probably have a higher priority (as it is done in the above script).

Answer (score 4):

Try to edit the file `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily`
and change `INTERVAL=`.

Then:

```
service atop restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I just installed atop 2.4.0 today on CentOS 7. I tried several things to change the interval of the running service, including the accepted answer here but no change to the service status.

I eventually saw success by editing `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily` to change `LOGINTERVAL=600` to `LOGINTERVAL=60` , which I confirmed via `systemctl status atop`

I know there is already an accepted answer but here is my experience with CentOS 7. I suppose I will find out later if this does what I want.

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS 7...

```
echo "LOGINTERVAL=60" >> /etc/sysconfig/atop
```

This file is being read by `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily`, but `$LOGINTERVAL` variable is used to modify time interval, so that simple command may fix.

Answer (score 2):

The new way to do this is by setting the interval from the environment file that overrides current definitions.

EnvironmentFile path will differ from distro to distro, but now you know where to apply the change:

```
# systemctl cat atop
...
[Service]
...
Environment=LOGINTERVAL=600
...
---> EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/atop <---
...

# sed -i '/LOGINTERVAL=600/LOGINTERVAL=60/' /etc/sysconfig/atop

# systemctl daemon-reload

# systemctl restart atop
```

Answer (score 1):

For Debian/Proxmox/Ubuntu and Centos 7 the below will do it perfectly.

```
sed -i 's/600/60/' /usr/share/atop/atop.daily
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart atop && service atop status
```

Before:

```
root@coby:~# service atop status
● atop.service - Atop advanced performance monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/atop.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-06-02 18:34:27 CEST; 27s ago
     Docs: man:atop(1)
 Main PID: 30801 (atop)
   CGroup: /system.slice/atop.service
           └─30801 /usr/bin/atop -a -R -w /var/log/atop/atop_20200602 600

Jun 02 18:34:27 coby systemd[1]: Started Atop advanced performance monitor.
root@coby:~#
```

After:

```
root@coby:~# sed -i 's/600/60/' /usr/share/atop/atop.daily
root@coby:~# systemctl daemon-reload
root@coby:~# systemctl restart atop
root@coby:~# service atop status
● atop.service - Atop advanced performance monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/atop.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-06-02 18:37:55 CEST; 4s ago
     Docs: man:atop(1)
 Main PID: 7186 (atop)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 8.6M
      CPU: 840ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/atop.service
           └─7186 /usr/bin/atop -a -R -w /var/log/atop/atop_20200602 60

Jun 02 18:37:55 coby systemd[1]: Started Atop advanced performance monitor.
root@coby:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the file " /etc/default/atop ", setting INTERVAL=60
2. Restart atop `systemctl restart atop.service`

Comment: If you look at any recent `/etc/default/atop`, you’ll see the comment “this file is no longer used and will be removed in a future release”, so I doubt your answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this file: /etc/sysconfig/atop

I'm on Centos6. Changing interval from 600 to 60 and then restarting the atop service:

```
service atop restart
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, please note that your post seems to mostly reiterate what [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532692/377345) already stated. If you want to add more details or context, please consider submitting an edit suggestion to that answer instead.

Comment: As AdminBee has pointed out, as well as being similar to user3347420's answer, your answer is also more or less the same as [Yegolev's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529439/97255) too